# How does AWS charge the Redshift Spectrum cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

AWS doc on the pricing of AWS Redshift Spectrum says that we pay for only TB scanned. However, I still need to create a Redshift cluster and specify instance type as well as how many nodes in the cluster. So my question is: does AWS charge for the created cluster? I'd assume that a cluster with 2 `dc2.8xlarge` nodes would be more expensive than a cluster with 2 `dc2.large` nodes, even for a Redshift Spectrum cluster, but I can't find any documentation that explicitly discusses this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift Spectrum is a querying engine service offered by AWS allowing customers to use only the computing capability of Redshift clusters on data available in S3 in different formats. This feature enables customers to add external tables to Redshift clusters and run complex read queries over them without actually loading or copying data to Redshift.

Since Redshift Spectrum is a built-in feature of Amazon Redshift, you need a redshift cluster.

To your question: Answer is yes. AWS charge for the created cluster. Yes even for redshift spectrum.

Here is the pricing [calculator](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/pricing/)

dc2.8xlarge 32  244 GiB 2.56TB SSD  7.50 GB/s   $4.80 per Hour
dc2.large   2   15 GiB  0.16TB SSD  0.60 GB/s   $0.25 per Hour

Comment: Thanks, @BigData-Guru. Do you know if AWS changes S3 usage, as Redshift Spectrum will call S3 APIs to get stored data?

Comment: S3 usage is the byte scanned.  With Redshift Spectrum, you can run SQL queries directly against the data in S3. You are charged for the number of bytes scanned from S3. Additional charges (of $5 to $6.25 per TB of data scanned) can be incurred depending on the Region. Byte numbers are always rounded up to the next megabyte, with a minimum of 10 MB per query. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-spectrum-query-charges/